# when controller accept the request body the new line(\n) get removed

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot, controller

Here i have made controller.

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "/api"
            , produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE
            , method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public Account account(@RequestBody String requestInString){
}
```

Here i have request which contain new line.

```
<Acc>
<Header><MessageType>Acc</MessageType>
<RequestType>01</RequestType>
<processDateTime>Wed Sep 12 18:57:13 IST 2018</processDateTime>
<correspondentID>000405001573</correspondentID>
</Header>
</Acc>
```

But the controller accept the whole request in one single line and the new lines(\n) get removed . Please anyone help why this new line get removed from request. 
Here is my request when controller accepted the request.

```
<Acc><Header><MessageType>Acc</MessageType><RequestType>01</RequestType><processDateTime>Wed Sep 12 18:57:13 IST 2018</processDateTime><correspondentID>000405001573</correspondentID></Header></Acc>
```

So in java when I place first request then this is what we get.

```
String str = "<Acc>\n" + 
                    "<Header><MessageType>Acc</MessageType>\n" + 
                    "<RequestType>01</RequestType>\n" + 
                    "<processDateTime>Wed Sep 12 18:57:13 IST 2018</processDateTime>\n" + 
                    "<correspondentID>000405001573</correspondentID>\n" + 
                    "</Header>\n" + 
                    "</Acc>";
```

When controller consume the request then it become.

```
   String requestInString = "<Acc><Header><MessageType>Acc</MessageType><RequestType>01</RequestType><processDateTime>Wed Sep 12 18:57:13 IST 2018</processDateTime><correspondentID>000405001573</correspondentID></Header></Acc>";
```

Comment: what is new line? can you give an example?

Comment: like \n in  string

Comment: can you highlight  `\n` in input? sorry i don't see it in input

Comment: Please find the above example.Actually i was hitting the request with postman that's why the new line was not present.